# AWS S3 file (redirected from AWS Lambda Function) responds to CORS preflight OPTIONS request with a 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have an AWS S3 bucket configured as a static website with the following CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I also have a Lambda function that redirects to a specific page on the aforementioned S3 bucket. Here is a gist of the code:

```
module.exports.endPoint = (event, context, callback) => {
  // Do some cool processing and on success:
  redirectToUrl(303, 's3-bucket.amazon.com/page.html', callback);
}

function redirectToUrl(statusCode, url, callback) {
    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            Location: url,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: '',
    };

    console.log('Redirecting with status code ' + statusCode + ' to ' + url);

    callback(null, response);
}
```

I'm able to access the S3 HTML page directly from the browser using the same URL in the code. Yes, the API domain is different from the S3 domain:

```
api.domain.com --> initiates the request (redirection)
sub.domain.com/page.html --> requested resource (redirection target)
```

The server responds to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request with a 403 error, and the browser reports the following error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'S3 File' (redirected from 'API Endpoint')
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I originally set up the site with Serverless Framework by adding the following lines to my serverless.yml:

```
SiteBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        BucketName: ${self:custom.siteName}
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          IndexDocument: index.html
          ErrorDocument: error.html
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedMethods:
                - GET
                - HEAD
              AllowedOrigins:
                - "*"
              MaxAge: 3000
    SiteBucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      DependsOn: "SiteBucket"
      Properties:
        Bucket: ${self:custom.siteName}
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: "*"
              Action:
                - "s3:GetObject"
              Resource:
                - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.siteName}/*"
```

Once the bucket was created via Serverless Framework and seeing the CORS errors, I finagled the CORS policy on S3 manually without success.

It's also worth noting that the S3 site is set up with CloudFront Distribution but I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

This should be an easy fix, but it's proving to be quite tough. Please help.

Comment: As stated in the title, it's a 403.

Comment: Having same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this supposed to include a proper URL:

```
redirectToUrl(303, 's3-bucket.amazon.com/page.html');
```

I think changing it to the following might fix your issue:

```
redirectToUrl(303, 'https://s3-bucket.amazon.com/page.html');
```

Comment: Trust me, that's not the problem. I just put something to show that the file is from S3 instead of the real URL.